# Unable to fill data in dropdown from $scope variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to fill data in dropdown in template file from $http post method in controller. I have also tried $timeout but it also didn't worked as well. Here is my controller post mathod.

```
$http.post('api/getRecords.php', dataObjCat).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $timeout(function(){
                 $scope.categories = data.data;
                 console.log($scope.categories);
              },3000)

            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
```

I have to post mathods like above (including above method), and both of them unable to fill in the dropdown.

I can print $scope variable in the post success. But unable to print it in the template file.

**Note: this functionality works very well in local machine but not working on server.**

Comment: Which url is called when it's running on server? You can  check in Chrome's developer tools panel in network [section](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview)

Comment: Show your data and your template.

Comment: Is it possible that your application on the "server" has a virtual directory instead of just a root off the host.  So instead of `http://myapp.mycomp.com/api` yours might be `http://myapp.mycomp.com/appname/api` ?  Or perhaps there is some minification going awry due to improper DI?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your server seems to respond correctly, your issue is most likely due to an issue in your html. You should make sure that you have an **ng-repeat** in the "option" tag to show your categories. Your code might look like this:

```html
<select ng-model="YOURMODELHERE">
  <option ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category}}</option>
</select>
```

Ideally, you should post your HTML for us to see what's wrong ;)